# How to do an advanced language filter on VSCode extension manifest?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I want my extension command menu to be listed in `commandPalette` iff the `languageId == php` and `fileExtension == .php4`

How can this be accomplished?

**Snippet of VSCode extension manifest:**

```
"commandPalette": [
   {
      "command": "extension.helloWorld",
      "when": "resourceLangId == php", // && fileExtension == .php4
   }
]
```

Comment: The workaround that worked for me was to use this filter `"when": "resourceLangId == php"` and then on my command code only do HelloWorld action only if the open document name ends with `*.php4` otherwise ignore the command invocation. 

- My TakeAway: At least this extension is only activated and invocable for PHP files only and only executed for `*.php4`.

Comment: Did you try `&& resourceExtname == .php4`